# How to read and concatenate files in fortran

Tags: file, binary, fortran

I got 5 files generated by a fortran code like this

```
longP=8
OPEN(unit=20,FILE="GMt_2.dat",ACTION="write",ACCESS='Direct',RECL=longP)
count1=1
do J=K,fact
READ(10,*)XA,XB,YA,YB,ZA,ZB,rho
call Grv('f',Nx,Ny,dimg,Dx,Dy,XO,YO,XA,XB,YA,YB,ZA,ZB,rho,G,elev,Svec)
do I=1,dimg
WRITE(UNIT=20,rec=count1)Svec(I)
count1=count1+1
end do
WRITE(*,*)J
end do
dim(2)=J-1
fact=fact+fact1
call flush(20)
CLOSE(20)
```

which returned with an unreadable file format, my professor said "its binary, machine code" My goal here is to concatenate the information in those 5 files in one array to perform some processing. how can I achieve this?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you show writes the data using unformatted I/O and direct access. You'll need to read it using unformatted I/O as well. You could use direct access or, and this would be my recommendation, stream access (ACCESS='STREAM' in the OPEN statement.) Open each file in sequence, read the data and then write it using the same mechanism to your single file. Your question is ambiguous enough to not allow a more detailed response.